# how to update html content of a div so that it looks smoothly to the user

Tags: html, angular

I've got this element in my template

```
<div [innerHTML]="doc"></div>
```

the **doc** is updated as user types in another box on the screen. The doc is being generated on server with regular time intervals and is returned back to the browser, where I update it in the component.

```
this.mdService.convert(this.text).subscribe(html => {
  this.doc = html
});
```

That works nicely with small fragments. But when those get bigger, redrawing HTML takes time and screen is sort of flickering. What would be a way to solve that problem?

Comment: create a spinner maybe or a skeleton loader until all the content is loaded into the div?

Comment: If a business accepts, generate doc on the front side and just confirm on backend.